# "unresolved import -- maybe a missing extern" When extern declaration exists

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a small project which built with no issues when it was all in one big .rs file. I wanted to make it easier to work with, so I broke it up into modules, and the project is now structured like this:

```
├── GameState
│   ├── ballstate.rs
│   ├── collidable.rs
│   ├── gamestate.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   └── playerstate.rs
├── lib.rs
└── main.rs
```

In `ballstate.rs`, I need to use the `rand` crate. Here's an abbreviated version of the file:

```
extern crate rand;

pub struct BallState {
    dir: Point,         
    frame: BoundingBox  
}                     

impl BallState {
    fn update_dir(&mut self) {
        use rand::*;                                                                                                                                                                    
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();                                                                      
        self.dir.x = if rng.gen() { Direction::Forwards.as_float() } else { Direction::Backwards.as_float()  };
        self.dir.y = if rng.gen()  { Direction::Forwards.as_float() } else { Direction::Backwards.as_float() };
    }                                                                                                        
}
```

However, when I run `cargo build` from the top level directory, I get the following error:

> GameState/ballstate.rs:42:9: 42:13 error: unresolved import `rand::*`. Maybe a missing `extern crate rand`?

When I just had the extern crate declaration in my main.rs file, this worked. What's changed now that it's in a separate module?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To quote from the [Crates and Modules chapter of the Rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html):

> [...] `use` declarations are absolute paths, starting from your crate root. `self` makes that path relative to your current place in the hierarchy instead.

The compiler is correct; there is no such thing as `rand`, because you've put it inside a module, so the correct path to it would be `GameState::ballstate::rand`, or `self::rand` from within the `GameState::ballstate` module.

You need to either move `extern crate rand;` to the root module *or* use `self::rand` within the `GameState::ballstate` module.

Comment: This is the answer I arrived at a few hours ago; thanks for posting (and for pointing out where in that book/tutorial this was stated, I actually read it before posting the question and didn't realize that it had the solution the whole time). I didn't mean to imply that the compiler was wrong, just that I didn't understand exactly what had changed from the one file scenario to the many.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `extern crate rand;` line in you `main.rs` and/or `lib.rs` file. No need to put it in the other files.

Perhaps it is related to [this bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27626).